# PyCharm JavaScript References Across .js Files

Tags: javascript, reference, pycharm

I'm currently stumped about a problem I'm facing where I can't reference functions and variables from one JavaScript file to the next.  I've tried adding all of the JavaScript files as a library in File->Settings->JavaScript->Libraries but with no success - I still get the gray underline for references with, for instance, a hover-over message that reads "Unresolved function or method ".

The strange thing is if I move a copy of the JavaScript files outside of the subversioned project directory and then add that project-external reference to File->Settings->JavaScript->Libraries then the references are found but this solution is not satisfactory because these JavaScript files are updated via subversioning daily (we're in development)

Does anybody have any insight to my problem?  If I am not going about this the right way then let me know.  What I ultimately want to be able to do is reference variables and functions from specfic JavaScript files across all my JavaScript files so that I can easily follow references (ctrl+leftclick) to insure the parts are fitting together properly.

Thanks!

(P.S. I'm using PyCharm 2.5)

Comment: It would help if you file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with a small sample project to reproduce this issue attached.

Comment: (on behalf of @pferretti): Have you tried to add your javascript files to sources in "Project Structure"?

Comment: Consider upgrading your PyCharm version if this problem still persists.